# Partial sync of Mysql databases on two remote computers

Tags: mysql, synchronization

Does mysql replication supports delayed sync if remote slave server is OFF?

For example I want to make my developing server have a fresh copy of databases each morning.

It should be partial sync, not full copy of databases each morning.

And synchronization should be only ONE way, not duplex, to avoid deleting something of master server.

What utilities are out there or native functionality of mysql itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup master-slave [mysql replication](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication). You can stop the slave whenever you want, and then start it again to make your slave up-to-date. The following mysql commands can be used:

```
> slave stop;
> slave start;
```

Comment: So when I'll launch slave start, it will automatically fill local slave databases ONLY with missing entries, not the full database copy right? Thanks btw :)

Comment: It should copy the pending changes only.

Comment: That's very good. :)

Answer (score 0):

mysql replication can work with interruptions but it makes sense only if there'll be no changes to the database content on the the dev-box. is it the case? if not - it'll be better if you either:

- make a full dump on the production and recover it on the test [mysqldump will come handy]

or

- use a tool like [pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html) to intelligently synchronize the content from production to the test without transferring all the data [this makes sense only if your database has larger size]